# Problem to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 on NVMe SSD

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, nvme

With the latest BIOS, as before actual install the ubuntu 18.04.2 OS from a USB CD, the system always hang, soon after either the "try ubuntu without install" or "install ubuntu" selection made.

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: check the sata mode in bios. it needs to be ACHI.

Comment: It needs to be AHCI

Comment: what about if there is no sata mode in bios available?  Called customer support, still any way to make it work?    Thanks